# How to assign properties to a user in an Array List?

Tags: java, arraylist

So far I have created an Array List which only currently consists of one user. For my assignment, I have been asked to print out properties for that user such as its username and userType. As far as I aware I have created an enhanced for loop that would print out these properties if only they were assigned. My question is how would I go about assigning these properties to my user? I have created a UserGroup class in which the array list resides in and a User class in which some details about the User is specified however I am not quite sure if the User class is correct for what I am trying to achieve. Here is the code for both classes:

UserGroup:

```
 package main;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserGroup {

    ArrayList<User> userGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    User userOne;

    public void addSampleData(String username, String userType, String name) {

    userGroup.add(new User("LeeB", "Staff", "Lee"));

}

    public User getUser(int index)  {

    return userGroup.get(0);

}

    public void printusername(){

       for (User x : userGroup)
           System.out.println(x);

    }
}
```

User:

```
 package main;
class User {

  String username;
  String userType;
  String name;


    User(String username, String userType, String name) {

    this.username = username;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.name = name;
    }

  public String getUsername() {
      return username;
  }

  public String getUserType() {
      return userType;
  }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public String setUserType(String admin) {
      return userType = admin;
  }

}
```

Main method:

```
package main;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int counter=2; counter<=40; counter+=2) {
       System.out.println(counter);
    }
    System.out.println("For loop complete.");

    int counter = 1;
    int increment = 2;
    int loopexeccounter = 0;
    while (counter <= 500) {
        loopexeccounter = loopexeccounter + 1;
        System.out.println(counter);
    counter = counter + increment++;
    }
System.out.print("This loop iteratted "+loopexeccounter+" times.");
}

    public Main() {

     UserGroup userGroupObject = new UserGroup();

 System.out.println(userGroupObject.getUser(0)); 
 }

}
```

Ignore everything above the latest method, it's just some examples of loops that they wanted us to print out.

Updated version, no errors but user(0) isn't being printed out.

Comment: `public Main()` is a *constructor*, not a method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far I have created an Array List which only currently consists of one user.

Actually, `user0` is never assigned. It's null, so you're only going to be adding null into the list.

You do not need `user0` variable.

```
ArrayList<User> userGroup = new ArrayList<>();
User userOne;

public void addSampleData(String username, String userType, String name) {
    userGroup.add(new User(username, userType, name));
}
```

Then,

```
public User getUser(int index)  {
    return userGroup.get(index);
}
```

If you want the first user, call that method with 0 as the parameter.

As far as this is concerned, it's fine, but see [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

```
public void printusername(){

   for (User x : userGroup)
       System.out.println(x);
}
```

Alternatively, if you just want `x`'s username, then print that instead of the entire object

Slightly more advanced option, since the Group essentially is a list of users.

```
public class UserGroup extends ArrayList<User> {
```

Or, you don't really need that class unless you add more specialized methods than `add`, `get`, and `print`

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: I think everything works apart from one thing, for the "int index" part of the getUser method, what would index be replaced with?

Comment: Nothing? `index` is the parameter name

Comment: Your would call `userGroupObject.getUser(0)`

Comment: Ah okay sorry, I got a little confused, thanks for your help!